# cout chr(10) adds a superfluous chr(13) before it

Tags: c++, printf, ipc, cout, bytestream

I have two c++ exes communicating over iostream. First exe sends a stream of chars (or bytes) and second intercepts this and decodes them.

exe1.exe emits chars:

```
void main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
    cout << static_cast<char>(i);
}
```

exe2.exe takes them in:

```
void main()
{
    FILE* pipe = _popen("exe1.exe", "rb");
    while (!feof(pipe))
        cout << static_cast<int>(fgetc(pipe)) << endl;
    _pclose(pipe);
}
```

One would expect to receive 256 values in serial order as so:
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13...

But one gets
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,**13**,10,11,12,13...

There is a problem at 10, where you can see an additional 13 before it. Possibly cout wants to be helpful by adding an extra carriage return before a \n char. But it is annoying when one wants to transfer pure bytes between two processes. Yes, cout is for human readability, but is there a way to tell cout or printf to not do that? Or to use another stream which is not intended for humans to read?

Comment: Something is adding DOS line endings to your output. The `10`, e.g. the `'\n'` is being translated into `"\r\n"` which is the DOS CRLF line ending. The fact you are opening `"exe1.exe"` hints you are on windows.

Comment: `cout` is in text mode.  Change to binary.

Comment: See also [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/2410359)

Comment: @chux Oh, good catch. That snuck right by.

Answer (score 0):

Character `10` is the ASCII `LF`, which is treated as a line break on most platforms.  On Windows specifically, the standard line break is a `13 10` (`CRLF`) sequence.  C++ stream implementations are smart enough to know that and will convert character `10` to `13 10` on output when operating in text mode.  If you don't want that to happen, you have to put the output stream into binary mode instead.